# Do I just need a VGA to RCA adaptor to stream video from my macbook to TV?

Tags: video, macbook-pro, video-adapter

I want to get the adaptor to stream videos from my macbook to my TV.

I already have the Apple adaptor from DVI to VGA: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDA4Mw&mco=MTM3NTA3MDU

I know need an adaptor from VGA to RCA.. I guess this one: http://www.bzsell.com/product_pic/10/05/16/flag_129185411642265983.JPG

But the guy at the store, told me that it is not that easy. If the TV is old (and it is), I need a video converter... (around 50 euros)

is that true ?
thanks

Comment: The Apple adaptor you linked to is [Mini DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) to VGA, not [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) to VGA -- which one does your MacBook actually have?  (It might also be [Mini-DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI) or [Micro-DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-DVI).)

Comment: @Gordon Davisson Mini-DVI sorry

Comment: In that case, see my comment on Martin's answer.  I should mention that the VGA-RCA adapter cable you linked to will NOT work at all -- it has the right connectors, but puts completely TV-incompatible signals on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* need a converter, but I don’t think so. Bear in mind that all those conversions will degrade the image a lot.

Does your TV have S-VGA? in that case you could use this [adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/M9319G/A) from Apple. Better than RCA anyway.

**edit** updated with the right adapter. As already noted, please remember that this doesn’t carry audio.

Comment: Since Patrick clarified that he has Mini-DVI output, [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/M9319G/A) is the appropriate adapter.  Also, note that this doesn't carry audio, you need a separate cable for that.